# Is there a word for in/out-ness?

Tags: general-topology

Is there a word that can be used to call the "in" or "out" value of some entity? I'm looking for a word that is akin to "sign" for "positive" or "negative" if there is such a word.

Example 1:
The XXX of the point is either inside or outside of the sphere (or on the sphere, but let's ignore that.)

Example 2: The XXX of this side of the line is inside.

What word could be used in place of XXX here? Perhaps "orientation" or "containment"?

EDIT:
Looks like there is a similar question posted here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41008/is-there-a-technical-term-for-insideout-ness

Comment: I'm not at all sure I understand your question.  The words "interior" and "exterior" exist.  Are you talking about geometric shapes, or what? $\qquad$

Comment: containment? can you be more specific about the "entity" @ThomasEding

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest "contained in", "not contained in", "included in", "excluded from", or "within". All seem to be acceptable terminology for talking about being "inside" or "outside" some entity.

In terms of your second question about what to call the characteristic of the object, that really depends. If you could be more specific about what attribute you want to talk about, I could be more helpful. For example, if you were talking about the position of a point, I would suggest just saying "the point" because position is the fundamental attribute of a point.

Answer (score 0):

With the example you gave, position is suitable (i.e. $XXX:='position')$. You may also be looking for something like "within". "The entity is within the object".